# Angular 5 webpack angular-router-loader not working and no errors

Tags: webpack, angular5, angular-router-loader

I'm facing an issue after angular 5 migration with lazy loading. In my webpack.config I'm using angular-router-loader but there is no error in console when I'm running in JIT mode and lazy modules never load.

When I run the app with ngTools for AOT compilation it works and I can see the generated chucks.

I already tried many solutions but the chucks aren't generated and when I navigate to lazyload route there is no error in console, it just won't load.

[Console logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMWyL.png)

```
// app.module
@NgModule({
 imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    MainPageModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, {
      useHash: true,
      // preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules
    })
  ]
});

// app.routing
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MainPageComponent } from './main_page/main.page.component';

    export const appRoutes: Routes = [
      { path: '', component: MainPageComponent },
      { path: 'dashboard', loadChildren: './_dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
      { path: 'lazyload', loadChildren: './lazyload/lazy.module#LazyModule' }
    ];


/** 
 * webpack.config
*/
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const { AngularCompilerPlugin } = require('@ngtools/webpack');

// Webpack Plugins
const CommonsChunkPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/CommonsChunkPlugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
const cssnano = require('cssnano');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const FaviconsWebpackPlugin = require('favicons-webpack-plugin');
const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');
const CheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').CheckerPlugin;
// const CompressionPlugin = require("compression-webpack-plugin");
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');

//Configurations
const optimizationConfig = require('./opt.config.json');
const tsLintConfig = require('./tslint.json');

/**
 * Env
 * Get npm lifecycle event to identify the environment
 */
const ENV = process.env.npm_lifecycle_event;
const isTestWatch = ENV === 'test-watch';
const isTest = ENV === 'test' || isTestWatch;
const isProd = ENV === 'build';
const isAOTWatch = ENV.includes('aot');
console.log('======== Running in mode: ' + (isAOTWatch || isProd ? 'AOT' : 'JIT'));

module.exports = function makeWebpackConfig() {
    /**
     * Config
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html
     * This is the object where all configuration gets set
     */
    let config = {};

    /**
     * Devtool
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool
     * Type of sourcemap to use per build type
     */
    if (isProd) {
        config.devtool = 'source-map';
    }
    else if (isTest) {
        config.devtool = 'inline-source-map';
    }
    else {
        config.devtool = 'eval-source-map';
    }

    /**
     * Entry
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
     */
    if (!isTest) {
        /**
         * Entry
         * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
         */
        config.entry = isTest ? {} : {
            'app': './src/config/main.ts', // Our angular app
            'polyfills': './src/config/polyfills.ts',
            'vendor': './src/config/vendor.ts'
        };
    }

    /**
     * Output
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#output
     */
    config.output = isTest ? {} : {
        path: root('__build__'),
        publicPath: isProd ? '/' : 'http://localhost:9000/',
        filename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js' : 'js/[name].js',
        sourceMapFilename: isProd ? 'js/[name].[hash].js.map' : 'js/[name].js.map',
        chunkFilename: isProd ? '[id].[hash].chunk.js' : '[id].chunk.js'
    };

    /**
     * Resolve
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
     */
    config.resolve = {
        // Only discover files that have those extensions
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json', '.css', '.scss', '.html']
    };

    let atlOptions = '';
    if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
        // awesome-typescript-loader needs to output inlineSourceMap for code coverage to work with source maps.
        atlOptions = 'inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false';
    }

    /**
     * Loaders
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-loaders.html
     * This handles most of the magic responsible for converting modules
     */
    config.module = {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(?:\.ngfactory\.js|\.ngstyle\.js|\.ts)$/,
                loaders: isProd || isAOTWatch ? ['@ngtools/webpack'] : [
                        '@angularclass/hmr-loader',
                        'awesome-typescript-loader?inlineSourceMap=true&sourceMap=false',
                        'angular2-template-loader',                        
                        'angular-router-loader'
                    ]
            },
            // Support for *.json files.
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json-loader'
            },

            // Load fonts
            {
                test: /\.woff(2)?(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "url-loader?mimetype=application/font-woff&name=./font/[hash].[ext]"
            },

            {
                test: /\.(ttf|eot|svg)(\?v=[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9])?$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=./fonts/[hash].[ext]"
            },

            // Load images
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|ico)$/,
                loader: "file-loader?name=./image/[hash].[ext]"
            },

            // SASS or SCSS loaded in src/app/_common
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                include: [root('src', 'app', '_common', 'plugins'), root('src', 'app', '_common', 'styles')],
                loader: isTest ? 'null-loader' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: ['css-loader'] })
            },

            // SASS or SCSS loaded in all components
            {
                test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                exclude: [root('src', 'app', '_common', 'plugins'), root('src', 'app', '_common', 'styles')],
                loader: 'raw-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader'
            },

            // Support for .html as raw text
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                loader: 'raw-loader',
                exclude: root('src', 'config')
            }
        ]
    };
    if (isTest && !isTestWatch) {
        // instrument only testing sources with Istanbul, covers ts files
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'post',
            include: path.resolve('src'),
            loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter-loader',
            exclude: [/\.spec\.ts$/, /\.e2e\.ts$/, /node_modules/]
        });
    }

    if (!isTest || !isTestWatch) {
        // tslint support
        config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.ts$/,
            enforce: 'pre',
            loader: 'tslint-loader'
        });
    }

    /**
     * Plugins
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
     */
    config.plugins = [
        // Define env letiables to help with builds
        // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#defineplugin
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            // Environment helpers
            'process.env': {
                ENV: JSON.stringify(ENV)
            }
        }),

        // Workaround needed for angular 2 angular/angular#11580
        /*  new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
              // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
              /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
              root('./src') // location of your src
          ),*/

        // Tslint configuration for webpack 2
        new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
            options: {
                /**
                 * Apply the tslint loader as pre/postLoader
                 * Reference: https://github.com/wbuchwalter/tslint-loader
                 */
                tslint: tsLintConfig,

                /**
                 * Sass
                 * Reference: https://github.com/jtangelder/sass-loader
                 * Transforms .scss files to .css
                 */
                sassLoader: {},

                /**
                 * PostCSS
                 * Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
                 * Add vendor prefixes to your css
                 */
                postcss: [
                    autoprefixer(optimizationConfig.autoprefixer),
                    cssnano(optimizationConfig.cssnano)
                ]
            }
        })
    ];
    if (isProd || isAOTWatch) {
        config.plugins.push(
            new AngularCompilerPlugin({
                tsConfigPath: './tsconfig.json',
                entryModule: root('src/app/app.module#AppModule')
            })
        );
    } else {
        config.plugins.push(
            new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
                /angular(\\|\/)core/,
                path.resolve('./src')
            )
        );
    }

    if (!isTest && !isProd) {
        config.plugins.push(new DashboardPlugin());
    }

    if (!isTest && !isTestWatch) {
        config.plugins.push(
            new CheckerPlugin(),

            // Generate common chunks if necessary
            // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html
            // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
            new CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: ['vendor', 'polyfills']
            }),

            // Inject script and link tags into html files
            // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                template: './src/config/index.html',
                chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
            }),

            // Extract css files
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
            // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
            new ExtractTextPlugin({
                filename: 'css/[name].[hash].css',
                disable: !isProd
            }),

            // Support favicons generation
            // Reference: https://github.com/jantimon/favicons-webpack-plugin
            new FaviconsWebpackPlugin({
                logo: './src/config/favicon.png',
                title: 'Glow Portal',
                prefix: 'favicon/',
                icons: {
                    android: false,
                    appleIcon: false,
                    appleStartup: false,
                    coast: false,
                    favicons: true,
                    firefox: false,
                    opengraph: false,
                    twitter: false,
                    yandex: false,
                    windows: false
                }
            }),

            // Module (value) is loaded when the identifier (key) is used as free letiable in a module.
            // Reference: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin
            new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                $: 'jquery',
                jquery: 'jquery',
                moment: 'moment',
                svgPanZoom: 'svg-pan-zoom'
            })
        );
    }


    // Add build specific plugins
    if (isProd) {
        config.plugins.push(
            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
            // Only emit files when there are no errors
            new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin(),

            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
            // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
            new UglifyJsPlugin(optimizationConfig.uglifyjs)

            // Reference: https://recordnotfound.com/compression-webpack-plugin-webpack-76201
            // Prepare compressed versions of assets to serve them with Content-Encoding
            /*new CompressionPlugin({
             asset: "[path].gz[query]",
             algorithm: "gzip",
             test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$/,
             threshold: 10240
             })*/
        );
    }

    /**
     * Dev server configuration
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devserver
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html
     */
    config.devServer = {
        contentBase: './__build__',
        historyApiFallback: true,
        stats: 'minimal',
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 1000
        }
    };

    return config;
}();

// Helper functions
function root(args) {
    args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return path.join.apply(path, [__dirname].concat(args));
}
```